# javascript infinitely loop over object every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a users object

```
var users = {
  one: {
            name: 'batman',
            age: 25
       },

  two: {
           name: 'spiderman',
           age: 27
       },

  three: {
            name: 'superman',
            age: 26
         }
}


var displayName = function(name) {
  console.log(name);
}

for(var name in users) {
  if(users.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    displayName(name);
  }
}
```

I want to loop over the object 'users' infinitely and call `displayName` function on every 5 seconds. So that it will display one single name after every 5 seconds.

Where is the best place to place the `setInterval` ?

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kijoyi/5/edit)

Comment: Each call should display the next name? Or each call display a random one?

Comment: @CarlierRobin Each call should display the next name in the object. If it reaches the end, the loop should start over again.

Comment: Have you considered using an array instead of that odd object with `one`,`two`,`three` properties?

Comment: well I used object because every key I need a list of properties that I will pass to the function.

Comment: Meh, if those property names have a meaning then OK (but notice that they don't have an order). Iterating integer keys would be much easier and give the collection a well-defined order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier if you change your `users` object to be a simple array:

```
var users = [
    {name: 'batman', age: 25},
    {name: 'spiderman', age: 27},
    {name: 'superman', age: 26}
];
```

**UPDATE:** ...but as you require `users` to remain an object we can simply build our own array of users directly from the object:

```
var users = {
one: {
        name: 'batman',
        age: 25
   },
two: {
       name: 'spiderman',
       age: 27
   },
three: {
        name: 'superman',
        age: 26
     }
};

//Build an array of users from the users object
var userArray = [],
    buildUserArray = (function(){
        for (key in users) {
            if (users.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                userArray.push(users[key]);
            }
        }
    })();

var displayNames = {
    max : userArray.length, 
    current : 0,
    timeout : null,
    go : function() {
        console.log(userArray[this.current]);//the whole user object
        console.log(userArray[this.current].name);//just the name
        this.current = (this.current+1) % this.max;//increment current position
        this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){displayNames.go();}, 500);
    },
    stop : function(){
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }
}
//to start
displayNames.go();
//set to stop after 5 seconds:
setTimeout(function(){displayNames.stop();}, 5000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9txjx9dy/1/ (updated)

Comment: I have used Object because I can quickly delete a key. But if use an array, in the delete scenario I would have to loop and check the value and then delete it. I feel Object is easier(Am I right on this one? )

Comment: Maybe. It depends on if you need to delete a specific key or just popping them off the end. FYI you can use `delete users[ index ]` to empty the object at that index, or `users.splice( index, 1 )` to completely remove it. Alternatively you can do as @hindmost does and build an array of names from the users object.

Answer (score 2):

You have to populate array of names and iterate through it.

And never don't use `setInterval`, use `setTimeout` instead.

```
var aNames = []; // array of names
for(var name in users)
    if(users.hasOwnProperty(name)) aNames.push(name);

var nNames = aNames.length, i = 0;
var displayNextName = function() {
    console.log(aNames[i]);
    i = (i + 1) % nNames;
    setTimeout(displayNextName, 5000);
}

displayNextName();
```

**UPDATE:**

Extended version with support of break/stop of infinite looping:

```
var aNames = [];
for(var name in users)
    if(users.hasOwnProperty(name)) aNames.push(name);

var nNames = aNames.length, i = 0;
var idTimeout;
var displayNextName = function() {
    console.log(aNames[i]);
    i = (i + 1) % nNames;
    idTimeout = setTimeout(displayNextName, 5000);
}
var stopDisplayNextName = function() {
    if (idTimeout) clearTimeout(idTimeout);
}

displayNextName();
```

Comment: and what if I have to stop the loop ?

Comment: Tip: `aNames = Object.keys(users);`

Comment: @Ajey Your question asked for infinite loop, I gave the answer.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the note. But `for ... in` syntax is compatible with obsolete browsers (like IE 8) unlike `Object.keys`.

Comment: +1 But this is logging the object keys `one, two, three` not the names `'batman','spiderman','superman'`

Comment: @hindmost why is it bad to use setInterval ?? Any internal hindrances?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var users = {
    one: {
        name: 'batman',
        age: 25
   },

    two: {
       name: 'spiderman',
       age: 27
    },

    three: {
        name: 'superman',
        age: 26
     }
    }
    var i=0;

    var displayName = function() {

    if(i==1) {
    console.log(users.one.name);
    }
    if(i==2) {
    console.log(users.two.name);
    }
    if(i==3) {
    console.log(users.three.name);
    }
    i= (i+1)%4;
    }


setInterval(function () {displayName(name)}, 3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var users = {
    one: {
        name: 'batman',
        age: 25
   },

    two: {
       name: 'spiderman',
       age: 27
    },

    three: {
        name: 'superman',
        age: 26
     }
    }


    var displayName = function(name) {
    console.log(name);
    }

    for(var name in users) {
        if(users.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        setInterval(function () {displayName(name)}, 3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only printing the last key in the object.!!

Answer (score -1):

```
var users = {
    one: {
        name: 'batman',
        age: 25
   },

    two: {
       name: 'spiderman',
       age: 27
    },

    three: {
        name: 'superman',
        age: 26
     }
    }
    var i=0;

    var displayName = function() {

    console.log(users[i%3].name);
    i= i+1;
    }


setInterval(function () {displayName()}, 3000);
```

Comment: users[i%3] is undefined. `users` is an object not an array.